# Subview (UILabel) doesn't respect the constraints when placed in superview (UITextView)

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitextview

I tried my own "placeholder in a `UITextView`" implementation.

My approach was this:

I create a `UILabel` in a `UITextView` subclass, and I set the constraints of the `UILabel` to match the size of its superview (`UITextView`).

This is the code where I create the `UILabel` and assign it to a class variable named `placeholderLabel` in `awakeFromNib()`:

```
placeholderLabel = UILabel()
placeholderLabel.text = placeholder
placeholderLabel.numberOfLines = 0
placeholderLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
placeholderLabel.textAlignment = .left
```

The following code is where I add the `UILabel` as a subview, and I set the constraints, again in `awakeFromNib()`:

```
placeholderLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
placeholderLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: textContainerInset.left + 4).isActive = true
placeholderLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: textContainerInset.top).isActive = true
placeholderLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: textContainerInset.right + 4).isActive = true
placeholderLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor, constant: textContainerInset.bottom).isActive = true
```

I also have a property where I set the placeholder's text, where I have a `didSet` observer, which sets `placeholderLabel`'s text and then calls `layoutIfNeeded()` in order to have the constraints recalculated in case the `UILabel` extends to a second (or third, etc) row:

```
var placeholder: String = "" {
    didSet {
        placeholderLabel.text = placeholder
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

The issue is that I have the following result:

[image]

**The `UILabel` extends beyond it's superviews bounds (to the right), and it appears that it doesn't respect the constraints.** I run the visual debugger which confirmed the same thing:

[image]
[image]

It seems that there is a width constraint which follows the `UILabel`'s content width instead of following the constraint I have set in place (*in this case it creates a width of 431 whereas the superview's width is 288*).

Is there something that I miss?

Comment: Can you show your `UITextView` subclass? Just looking at what's happening, I'm guessing the label, much like in a scroll view, is setting the content size of the text view, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to use a negative value for the right constraint's constant (or - to use a positive value - switch the items `placeholderLabel.rightAnchor` / `rightAnchor`).

The real problem though is the fact that `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. In your case adding the `UILabel` with a large text as a subview and constraining its edges to the textview's edges results in the textview's `contentSize` to grow. The textview becomes horizontally scrollable.

Printing out the textview's `contentSize` before and after adding the label results in different values for the width (before: 335.0, after: 505.0).

Proof: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eogvl2c5r76c6cl/example.mov?dl=0

You could work around that problem by not creating the right but a width constraint instead:

```
// placeholderLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -(textContainerInset.right + 4)).isActive = true
placeholderLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, constant: -(textContainerInset.left + 4 + textContainerInset.right + 4)).isActive = true
```

Comment: You were absolutely right. Lesson learnt: first check inheritance in documentation

Answer (score 0):

with right should be minus

```
placeholderLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: - textContainerInset.right - 4).isActive = true
```

Comment: I have tried that too, that's not the issue (if you see how the constraints are resolved the extra distance is only 4 points, and the label extends way beyond that)

Comment: The constant is clearly not the issue here. Even if by placing 10 worked it still doesn't solve the underlying problem.

Comment: i think the insets is changed at runtime when you edit and be larger than 4 but yeah it's weird